# Qt QDialog and GNOME 3, how to display the close button/title bar and make it movable?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, gnome-3

In GNOME 3 when displaying any QDialog it appears that it can't be moved and it has no title bar.

Is there a way to re-enable the title bar and make it movable? I attempted to use a QMainWindow as a workaround instead but it appears in the task bar and won't appear as a "modal" dialog.

Comment: Note that "modal" only makes sense in the context of windows.
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#modal-prop

Comment: The behavior of modal dialogs is a "feature" of Gnome 3. Generally speaking you probably shouldn't try to mess with the default behavior of the windowing system. Also note that this behavior is configurable from within Gnome3 itself, so if you leave it alone then the user can still choose how they want it to behave.

Comment: Thanks @Chris I guess I'll just leave it be then even though it makes my app look bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, it might help you:

1. Install Configuration Editor (dconf-editor)
2. Open it: **Alt+F2**, enter **dconf-editor**, press **Enter**
3. Go to: **/org/gnome/shell/overrides** and select **attach_modal_dialogs**
4. Change **Use default value** to **OFF**
5. Change **Custom value** to **False**

[image]

Type **r** in Alt+F2 prompt to restart Gnome shell and see the changes (QDialogs should become movable).

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem with a dialog (at least the no title bar part), I fixed the issue by setting the dialog's parent to be nullptr as opposed to setting a real parent.

http://blog.pitonyak.org/node/18

Now, that said, setting the configuration option in gnome is probably a better solution if it works (and I did not verify it). My only complaint with the solution is that then it will behave differently on another computer. Then again, one could argue that the point of having the configuration option is that the owner of that machine can decide.